# i cant get my footer to stay at the base for some reason

Tags: html, css, web

Have tried alot, all versions of position. It WILL stay at the bottom on one page. but not on some. so very weird.

```
.footer {

width: 100%;
height: auto;
background-color: #17aa1f;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
bottom: 0;

}

.footer-info li {
 color: white;
 list-style-type: none;
}
<footer>
    <div class="footer">
        <ul class="footer-info">
            <li>ex</li>
            <li>Contact on:</li>
            <li>ex@gmail.com</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</footer>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `position: relative;` on your `.footer` won't do anything as that container would just make it relative to the parent which is your container `<footer>`. Use `position: absolute;` instead as that would make the class be anchored to the DOM instead. See the snippet below for your reference:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #17aa1f;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.footer-info li {
  color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <footer>
    <div class="footer">
      <ul class="footer-info">
        <li>ex</li>
        <li>Contact on:</li>
        <li>ex@gmail.com</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

More on `position` property [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Answer (score 0):

*I think You Don't need to use position whan you add footer tag*

**Don't Add any tag or any text below footer tag**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }

      body {
        height: 100vh;
      }

      .footer {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        background-color: #17aa1f;
        text-align: center;
        bottom: 0;
      }

      .footer-info li {
        color: white;
        list-style-type: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, animi quasi
    vitae natus labore blanditiis totam eligendi dolorem voluptate nisi
    voluptatibus ut hic provident distinctio pariatur perferendis quidem ad
    facilis quaerat esse corporis, perspiciatis cum tempora. Nobis quos eos quis
    dolorem, odit officia consequuntur reprehenderit accusantium mollitia
    aliquam odio ex veritatis temporibus laboriosam placeat blanditiis
    voluptatem. Placeat dignissimos beatae quas distinctio officia iure
    molestias nostrum non animi id ex itaque, vero consectetur labore obcaecati.
    Hic maiores veritatis expedita cum eum ipsa esse quisquam? Culpa pariatur
    nostrum debitis tempora consectetur, temporibus voluptas totam possimus
    praesentium corporis sapiente modi doloremque ut dignissimos aliquam qui
    molestias officia dolorum facere facilis ad enim. Laborum inventore quae
    incidunt odit vitae molestias, voluptatibus deleniti sint eos culpa nam,
    obcaecati atque illo mollitia. Corporis, laboriosam! Earum sed praesentium
    ipsam blanditiis voluptas voluptatum commodi. Error qui quo dolore assumenda
    sit maiores omnis dolorem inventore laudantium, aliquam amet at commodi in
    quae, porro esse cum molestiae eligendi ratione cupiditate neque
    consequuntur earum? Eius rerum praesentium consequatur aliquam numquam in
    beatae ad tempore sequi, quibusdam mollitia repudiandae debitis temporibus,
    recusandae aut! Quibusdam, culpa atque reiciendis tempora repellat
    distinctio quo deserunt? Commodi ab dicta nobis aliquid quas corrupti
    dolores magni quam ad fugit perspiciatis, pariatur ipsam laborum molestias.
    Accusantium vero perspiciatis tempora facilis assumenda enim consequuntur
    perferendis minima, aliquid debitis iure voluptate molestias, sapiente
    pariatur sequi quisquam sit neque atque dolor saepe autem ut animi fugiat
    numquam. Temporibus tenetur nesciunt ipsam numquam quaerat inventore autem
    voluptates velit unde sapiente, dolor nam, doloribus sit eos dolore aliquam
    corporis optio explicabo enim alias quis? Error rem facere provident
    inventore deleniti repellat possimus repellendus obcaecati, deserunt facilis
    quis, similique eum debitis magnam dolor, praesentium cumque atque sapiente
    expedita iusto sed! Maxime rerum inventore mollitia cupiditate, quae
    consectetur iure ad explicabo architecto dolor voluptatum laborum voluptates
    voluptatibus adipisci ipsum veniam recusandae nihil molestias, suscipit,
    consequuntur ea porro praesentium? Dolorem, iusto obcaecati. Id fugit est,
    magnam, placeat repellendus voluptatem dolorem libero tempore nisi dicta
    nulla qui quod esse ab numquam exercitationem porro perspiciatis explicabo
    iure? Cupiditate, expedita! Recusandae itaque quae sapiente, amet eius fuga
    commodi cupiditate vitae quis! Saepe molestias, quidem odit ex dignissimos
    et numquam pariatur soluta. Nisi, nulla? Inventore quis maiores, similique
    sunt officia architecto culpa voluptatum nostrum corrupti expedita
    reiciendis neque, quae exercitationem necessitatibus quo eius pariatur
    mollitia dolores numquam, quos natus eveniet voluptate provident. Beatae
    ipsum eaque sit illum, libero, facilis repellat possimus reiciendis quia cum
    quo, enim voluptatum. Et voluptatibus maxime atque quia magni nostrum iure.
    Aspernatur, voluptatum! Enim iste necessitatibus nostrum minima voluptatum
    atque quis nisi at, esse vel voluptates maxime dolore dignissimos, dicta
    aliquam quam qui numquam, saepe dolorum ullam. Accusamus voluptatibus at
    mollitia necessitatibus, aperiam reprehenderit hic inventore qui tempore.
    Doloribus, autem expedita molestiae voluptatum totam necessitatibus debitis
    impedit amet eum! Nostrum earum aliquam quidem ratione vel pariatur
    quibusdam inventore nam quis, alias impedit, mollitia at sit itaque, quia
    totam consequuntur doloremque autem? Possimus sit autem et in aliquid, odio
    commodi tempore nobis porro. Exercitationem sit laborum officia ducimus
    earum voluptates similique cumque totam, quas alias quibusdam rem est
    adipisci magnam quam maxime sapiente asperiores distinctio error ad impedit
    architecto. Cupiditate nulla consequatur repellat commodi quae sunt, autem
    delectus necessitatibus consectetur fugiat, quasi placeat a debitis mollitia
    asperiores alias in corporis, aliquid corrupti reprehenderit nam qui non
    voluptatem! Nesciunt a modi ut ab sint, sed corrupti mollitia quibusdam
    quos, nisi fuga ipsum sunt ullam in perferendis? Distinctio iusto quod quia?
    Deserunt quisquam consectetur aut eius laborum nam eveniet, dolor porro
    nihil. Quia tempora asperiores sapiente quidem magni at rem, corporis dolor,
    labore iste earum eveniet reiciendis, laudantium consequatur. Fugiat odio id
    dolor ad non corporis, earum numquam voluptatibus maiores quae, doloribus
    itaque. Placeat possimus provident adipisci fuga eum reprehenderit delectus
    sapiente itaque. Neque vitae veniam velit perspiciatis nesciunt enim facilis
    soluta fuga nulla dignissimos voluptates quod reiciendis quaerat, porro
    sapiente? Repellat saepe fugit quaerat, unde vero molestias! Numquam autem
    neque ipsa beatae quisquam commodi. Recusandae nesciunt quia esse voluptates
    veniam qui! Quod maiores consequatur veniam natus rerum totam iste,
    praesentium beatae exercitationem eos non alias voluptas harum quos quidem
    ut, quaerat quis, aspernatur expedita iure molestias distinctio! In adipisci
    modi deserunt repellat obcaecati ducimus, ut laborum similique aperiam
    assumenda, quia ab aliquam alias itaque doloremque corrupti quasi vero nobis
    aut sit reiciendis facilis fugit molestiae explicabo? Optio sit possimus ex
    quas hic repellat laborum iste repudiandae minus perferendis provident
    reiciendis, delectus sed eveniet vitae. Iste laboriosam, illum quas
    provident nostrum ducimus saepe atque vitae! Enim aut voluptatibus
    laudantium eum error qui modi, molestiae a. Maxime, molestiae perspiciatis
    maiores quia soluta vero. Quidem aliquid culpa possimus, rerum quibusdam in
    maxime animi ipsam architecto blanditiis corporis? Laudantium iure earum
    voluptatem a, cupiditate porro id assumenda quisquam est consequuntur cum
    obcaecati distinctio unde asperiores architecto! Deserunt excepturi nihil
    amet voluptate nesciunt, placeat aut, iure architecto veritatis pariatur
    blanditiis aspernatur quasi. Laboriosam ipsam labore excepturi aspernatur
    sapiente aut totam vel, impedit et laudantium! Necessitatibus, consequatur
    tempora dolores quaerat aliquid sint labore sequi dolore saepe a eos
    pariatur itaque facilis sed, deleniti hic aperiam optio eius. Est cumque,
    alias quaerat tempore perferendis maxime. Est pariatur sed veniam fugit,
    architecto possimus a cumque provident maxime voluptatem quaerat adipisci
    voluptates accusamus sint omnis alias doloribus explicabo nam. A asperiores
    nisi reiciendis ut nostrum quam officiis labore iste repellat, laudantium
    autem in fugit perferendis optio necessitatibus quod laboriosam incidunt non
    sint. A facere animi error odio cumque obcaecati ad repellendus ut quam
    omnis dignissimos assumenda facilis quis sunt sint, aliquam nisi quo
    laudantium eaque totam libero repellat repudiandae veritatis velit. Libero
    ad dicta aliquid incidunt eum voluptate reprehenderit necessitatibus aperiam
    commodi, quae eos iste reiciendis! Excepturi minima a incidunt id, vero esse
    alias assumenda dolores dolore magni possimus voluptatibus eaque dicta quam
    enim saepe, veniam, explicabo modi architecto ullam similique! Earum minima
    laudantium tempore! Quisquam quo esse nulla impedit architecto est
    cupiditate alias neque accusamus error repellat, ad blanditiis eos enim,
    sint, perspiciatis quam mollitia eius maxime natus. Voluptatum a
    voluptatibus ab autem molestias obcaecati veritatis! Lorem, ipsum dolor sit
    amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium suscipit omnis est nemo quod
    aliquid totam, accusantium nisi, id sequi ex aspernatur molestias quaerat?
    Harum asperiores libero, minus exercitationem ut distinctio repudiandae
    sunt, laboriosam veniam soluta quisquam possimus dicta placeat a molestias
    repellat porro eius sint earum voluptates voluptate nisi amet voluptatibus?
    Quam commodi dicta voluptatibus a voluptates tempore, labore nihil ipsa
    voluptatem inventore. Quas repudiandae ipsa deleniti minus error harum
    repellat incidunt, iste maiores velit quia quibusdam iusto officiis, quasi
    autem tempora magni aut recusandae, adipisci accusantium. Reprehenderit, in
    repellendus libero nulla impedit tempora temporibus officiis error earum
    laboriosam neque nobis similique soluta hic totam eligendi beatae ipsam
    nostrum incidunt veritatis eos! Ipsam blanditiis cum reiciendis porro
    voluptatum corrupti itaque totam nostrum explicabo qui ut modi, et iste amet
    officiis assumenda a. Voluptatem ab repellendus autem alias reprehenderit
    voluptas cupiditate minus earum ratione. Et repellat minus dignissimos
    labore pariatur reprehenderit quisquam provident quas, accusamus assumenda
    ut omnis cumque fugit obcaecati culpa amet ullam sint ad sit porro voluptas.
    Eligendi dolorum enim excepturi vero nam? Ex error sed autem, asperiores
    temporibus, repellat sint earum delectus eaque saepe blanditiis. Impedit sed
    corporis nam, praesentium, fuga distinctio consectetur fugiat aspernatur
    quis id, veritatis nulla ipsam similique quos aliquid suscipit assumenda
    dignissimos nihil eos laborum vero ducimus ad dolorum. Assumenda ducimus
    magnam facere veniam ut fugit hic! Consectetur quos, dolor alias laboriosam
    praesentium hic quis voluptates nihil laborum assumenda quod autem modi
    magni rem ea. Voluptatibus in debitis veniam minima. Consequuntur cum eius
    possimus non, molestiae, mollitia eos fugit aliquid corrupti quod debitis,
    beatae error voluptatibus impedit pariatur iusto? Omnis voluptas laboriosam
    repellat iure blanditiis perferendis vel praesentium sint corrupti
    necessitatibus eos, dignissimos quo quisquam deserunt, ad nisi nostrum?
    Cumque dolores quos corporis sint sit fugit dolore numquam praesentium.
    Dolor delectus eaque eos molestias, velit assumenda vel explicabo, in odio,
    minima possimus nam iure aperiam totam dolore nisi. Quasi repellendus
    perspiciatis deserunt vel et inventore excepturi soluta rem libero
    cupiditate! Distinctio id necessitatibus voluptatibus expedita quasi et quae
    laborum eos recusandae maiores vel iste libero deserunt quia dolorem magnam
    iusto, fugiat rem repellendus. Quas incidunt velit deleniti fuga quaerat
    beatae corporis perferendis animi cupiditate asperiores perspiciatis dolorum
    saepe quia praesentium accusamus laboriosam, explicabo optio dolor quasi
    nulla atque repellendus eaque dolores dignissimos. Accusamus autem possimus
    asperiores neque sit debitis? Corrupti accusamus, ea eaque expedita aliquid
    minus eum nulla voluptatum modi provident, eos nihil! Magni ipsam asperiores
    quis, amet ipsa dolor magnam quisquam perferendis necessitatibus aspernatur
    ratione, reiciendis, rerum cumque quo? A maxime, ex iste quo quidem commodi,
    eaque minima ipsa dolorum voluptatum rerum dignissimos officiis minus at hic
    inventore sunt, voluptatibus reprehenderit! Est ipsa esse tempora atque ut
    enim vero culpa rerum officiis dicta, at sed, illum dignissimos labore nisi
    error neque, tempore eligendi in adipisci! Ratione error autem voluptas ad
    perspiciatis qui voluptates praesentium ducimus accusamus explicabo facere
    rerum, exercitationem pariatur velit! Totam, quam! Officia alias magnam
    suscipit id sunt sit quasi repellat cupiditate libero assumenda. Aliquid
    molestiae quae assumenda nisi recusandae nam! Nulla iste odit dignissimos,
    ipsum ab et iusto, quisquam esse accusantium, eum aspernatur magni mollitia
    voluptate quo libero consectetur. Voluptates eos doloribus commodi harum
    pariatur quibusdam molestiae animi saepe iusto quidem, error tempora
    expedita aliquam. Quo beatae doloremque voluptas repellendus illum iure
    iusto, quam molestiae perferendis. Consequuntur pariatur cumque aut deserunt
    deleniti dolorem quidem! Voluptatum possimus vitae exercitationem facilis,
    architecto accusamus, labore quae et dolores tempore, atque nostrum! Non
    delectus iste sequi cumque beatae fugiat eaque vel. Dolor perspiciatis,
    eveniet dolorem aliquam nemo nisi illo laborum tempora autem iste accusamus
    id vitae unde. Laborum consequatur culpa ratione vero odio ab eos doloribus
    a debitis quod aliquid labore iure, exercitationem aperiam excepturi?
    Tempore expedita iure temporibus? Temporibus, saepe nemo? Iusto reiciendis
    et ut vero voluptate mollitia magni quasi ipsum quisquam! Obcaecati fugit
    repellendus aut exercitationem ullam dolore consectetur quam quis fuga
    dignissimos accusamus, doloribus aperiam perferendis atque eos sint rem
    adipisci eius dolorem? Natus architecto magnam tempore blanditiis dolor
    iusto numquam nisi nam voluptatum sequi. A dolorem facilis tenetur suscipit,
    nesciunt dignissimos autem molestias officiis. Praesentium, quod quidem.
    Fugit sapiente voluptate quos! Cum aspernatur voluptates excepturi ipsum,
    fuga nobis, quo in reiciendis quibusdam obcaecati reprehenderit
    exercitationem doloremque molestias saepe repudiandae placeat! Ullam
    blanditiis id dolore laboriosam voluptatum a quasi nesciunt minima expedita
    excepturi mollitia, est, quibusdam velit repellendus aliquam dolores, libero
    iure. Vitae, aspernatur exercitationem vero rerum quae labore fugit
    cupiditate distinctio libero a laboriosam ab tempore reiciendis modi minima
    alias inventore minus eius veritatis maiores ipsum nam. Amet esse provident
    fugit doloribus quo ducimus molestias minima aliquam consequatur eligendi
    architecto earum voluptatibus cumque, voluptas magni, nesciunt quod
    temporibus suscipit aut aspernatur, ex praesentium beatae. Natus nam harum
    est exercitationem consequatur iste nulla quo nobis atque delectus voluptate
    sunt quibusdam fugit, cupiditate voluptatem inventore et soluta perspiciatis
    nostrum sit aliquam maiores praesentium. Repellat asperiores provident
    dolorem illo, expedita rem quam doloremque porro repudiandae atque
    aspernatur nobis quibusdam necessitatibus eos labore quia accusamus adipisci
    iure magnam eligendi est voluptates repellendus incidunt perferendis? Sed
    nihil voluptatibus beatae molestias fuga vel velit, excepturi itaque ipsa
    culpa voluptatum! Autem delectus nemo dolor numquam et esse molestiae, in
    similique impedit sunt, possimus, quasi soluta harum illum. Porro dicta
    nostrum quisquam ipsa reiciendis autem. Aperiam amet aut delectus enim ab ad
    labore eum ullam perspiciatis. Totam repellat suscipit voluptatum in! Aut
    sed, adipisci amet pariatur veniam odit exercitationem eos repellendus
    accusamus doloremque perspiciatis recusandae officia quam architecto quasi
    accusantium delectus dignissimos repudiandae. Deserunt sed expedita eos in
    omnis? Omnis quaerat optio quidem incidunt consequuntur, dignissimos aut
    minima. Fuga aliquam veniam, unde nostrum reiciendis recusandae. Ipsum
    perspiciatis exercitationem ad voluptatum maiores et tempora quisquam
    reprehenderit. Officiis fugiat aspernatur, nobis veritatis nam
    exercitationem provident rerum explicabo rem maiores distinctio porro sed,
    voluptatibus magni doloribus, amet magnam non et iste dolorem voluptates
    dicta. Ex, modi. Voluptate odit quam soluta vero velit ea sapiente ratione
    deleniti harum asperiores, nobis voluptatibus, culpa nulla, illum
    consectetur. Laborum, eaque quibusdam animi, in sapiente distinctio ipsa,
    iure exercitationem nisi magni voluptatibus aperiam natus omnis.
    <footer>
      <div class="footer">
        <ul class="footer-info">
          <li>ex</li>
          <li>Contact on:</li>
          <li>ex@gmail.com</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```